# Добавить элемент в многомерный массив JQuery

Tags: jquery, массивы

Есть такой массив

```
var grafik = [
          { data: [[1, 0], [2, 10]]}
        ];
```

Как в него записывать новые координаты по клику ?
Нажимаешь кнопку $('#button').click();

И в массив добавляется новые координаты, например:

```
grafik = [
          { data: [[1, 0], [2, 10], [3, 20]]}
        ];
```

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы можете изменить формат данного массива? Сейчас он выглядит нелепо.
Скорее это должен быть объект.

`var chart = {
   data: [
      [1, 0],
      [2, 10],
      [3, 20],
   ]
}`. Соответственно тогда решение будет `chart.data.push([4, 30])`. Ну или опишите подробнее что требует задача, подумаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  grafik[0].data.push([3, 20]);
});
```